# Assets 2 having problems indexing 12'000 files.

Tags: assets

since a few days I am trying to index about 12'000 pictures. it always stops at about the two third...

What could I do to make this happen?
Is there a way that I could reverse indexing, like starting from the other end?

Also, the thumbnails generation process is very slow...

- I've upped my php limit to 256MB, but that didn't change a lot.
- I am running the backend from within the system folder, and not from system.php, could that be a problem?
- It's indexing fine on other directories - it's really the amount of images that is causing a problem.
- the error log states nothing

I am on EE 2.5.5 and Assets 2.1.3.

Comment: outline4 - are you seeing any JS errors in your debug console?  I'd like to have a look at this; if available, please email super admin and FTP access to support@pixelandtonic.com; please reference this thread and include which upload directory is giving you trouble. Thank you!

Comment: hi lisa, I am sorry - I found another solution that involved only 2500 fotos. that way now all works.

Comment: No worries, outline4! If you do want to explore this again in the future, please let us know. :)

Comment: hi lisa... I found that even the solution with 2000 photos is incredibly slow! almost inusable... would you be so kind and have a look at the backend? but it's on a hidden domain... do you know how to rewrite the host files?

Comment: Hey outline4 - I'd recommend emailing support@pixelandtonic.com with a link to this thread. :)  I suspect you have  a permission issue with your cache of image upload folders...